# kafka-console-consumer.bat command does not working?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have produce message using Kafka producer in java application and I had consumed message from Kafka Server smoothly..
But suddenly I cant run the command '''kafka-console-consumer.bat''' in the command prompt. It doesn't display any error message..
[image: when I try to execute the command to see the attributes]

I have tried to consume message from the Kafka server through the command '''kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic student-details''' where the '''student-details''' is the Topic name
[image: ..]

But the command doesn't working.. Is there any alternative way to consume message

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to write code for a consumer, or use any other tool available. I prefer `kcat` on the CLI.

To debug your problem, you could edit Kafka's log4j.properties to increase the log level of the consumer.

Or, depending on how much time elapsed between "now", and "working perfectly", your topic is empty.